# Remove large file from git commit

Tags: git

I added a 150MB video to my projects source files and, unawarely, committed it. I then tried to `git push` the commit to my remote repo and noticed the the push **hung** for a while and then eventually failed, spitting out this:

```
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 145.48 MiB | 138.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (13/13), completed with 12 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 8b4191f1a1055e7dea4412f80b5125d2
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File src/images/greystone_place.mp4 is 145.45 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I tried adding the file to `.gitignore` but it was too late. Subsequent `git push` commands yielded the same result.

Next, I tried to reset HEAD --soft to the commit where I originally committed the large file (this was after a few more commits involving `.gitignore`). From there, I reset the file in question using `git reset HEAD -- path/to/filename` to the working directory and committed again. Doing this, I still ran into the same error.

I later realized that maybe using the `--amend` command would do the trick (based on [this article](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history)), but this also didn't work.

I also tried using `git rm --cached path/to/file` while I was in a soft reset. This also failed.

I have begun reading about `git rebase i` and `git filter-branch` but they seem complicated and I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree with this approach.

I am not a Git expert but in a nutshell, I want to do a `git push` with my other changes and exclude this large file. Somehow, it seems to be intertwined in an earlier commit and is preventing me from making a `push` to my remote repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [the tutorial on GitHub about removing file from history](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository),  you can use the [`bfg` tool](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) or use `git filter-branch` as you mentioned in your question:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

After that, you may need a force push (`git push -f`), since the history is modified.

> I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree with this approach.

You may have an backup first :-) And GitHub may be another backup (since your push failed).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily via the following command,

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

You can also delete it locally with the hash.

```
git reset --hard <SHA-Code>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will this command obliterate everything after the commit that I'm resetting to? I don't want to lose my other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler approach:

- git clone your GitHub repository again, in a new separate folder
- report your modifications there (without the huge file) (you could also cherry-pick past non-pushed commits from older repository)
- add, commit and push.